# Вместо xs отображается sm, все мелкое, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Когда просматриваю с мобильного устройства все очень мелкое, навигация не сворачивается. Вижу, что показывает как для планшета, даже если экран меньше 767px.
Можно прямо с Chrome в режиме мобильного устройства проверить?
Не пойму в чем ошибка, где баг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, все просто:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```